# Custom Options Description Field Magento

Tags: magento, e-commerce

First off, I've got a good understanding of Magento. I just wanted a simple answer on whether or not it would be wise for me to venture down this path.

I'm working on a vinyl printing retail business that allows customers to customize their products online. We want to add a custom option for font type but they would like their customers to visualize the fonts. There's an extension I found that does this for me but it's not free, which really isn't a problem.

While I was reading the comments for said extension, I stumbled upon another users site that has a simple description under the drop down box with a link. This seems like an opportunity to save a little bit of cash.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdPIr.jpg

TL;DR Do I pay $90 for an extension or is it going to be easier for me to add an extra description/link to my custom option

thanks